# Angularjs problem: cannot resolve variable, but variable exists

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm doing a project for University where I have a login for a website and I have to implement some operations. My issue is to maintain user session when a user is logged; so, if I open the website in a new tab, I want to be logged with the account of the main tab.
This is my angularjs code for the loginController:

```
mainAngularModule
    .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'AuthFactory',
        function ($scope, $state, AuthFactory) {

            let ctrl = this;
            ctrl.authRequest = {username: 'admin', password: 'password'};
            ctrl.doLogin = doLoginFn;


            ctrl.authMessage = '';


            //check if user already logged
            let logSession = localStorage.getItem(("authinfo"));

            if(logSession == null){
                console.log("logSession null");
            }

            if(logSession == undefined){
                console.log("isundefined");
            }

            if(logSession != null){
                console.log("not null");
                console.log("usern: " + logSession.username);
                //console.log("authinfo authorities: " + logSession.authorities)
                AuthFactory.setJWTAuthInfo(logSession);
                $state.go("dashboard.home");
            }


            console.log("login authinfo: " + localStorage.getItem("authinfo"));


            let sessionStorage_transfer = function(event) {
                if(!event) { event = window.event; } // ie suq
                if(!event.newValue) return;          // do nothing if no value to work with
                if (event.key === 'getSessionStorage') {
                    // another tab asked for the sessionStorage -> send it
                    localStorage.setItem('sessionStorage', JSON.stringify(sessionStorage));
                    // the other tab should now have it, so we're done with it.
                } else if (event.key === 'sessionStorage' && !sessionStorage.length) {
                    // another tab sent data <- get it
                    var data = JSON.parse(event.newValue);
                    for (var key in data) {
                        sessionStorage.setItem(key, data[key]);
                    }
                }
            };

// listen for changes to localStorage
            if(window.addEventListener) {
                window.addEventListener("storage", sessionStorage_transfer, false);
            } else {
                window.attachEvent("onstorage", sessionStorage_transfer);
            }



            function doLoginFn() {
                console.log("doLoginFn");
                var requiresLogin = $state.jwtToken;
                console.log("requireLogin: " + requiresLogin);
                AuthFactory.sendLogin(ctrl.authRequest, successCB, errorCB);

                function successCB(response) {
                    let authInfo = response.data;
                    console.log("data = " + response.data.all);
                    let header = response.headers();
                    authInfo.jwtToken = header['authorization'];

                    console.log("authInfo", authInfo);

                    // AuthFactory.user.username = authInfo.username;
                    // AuthFactory.user.role = authInfo.role;
                    let debugJWT = true;
                    //if (debugJWT) {
                    if (true) {
                        console.log(authInfo);
                        console.log("username: " + authInfo.username);
                        console.log("roles: " + JSON.stringify(authInfo.authorities));
                        console.log("jwtToken: " + authInfo.jwtToken);
                        console.log("userType: " + authInfo.userRole);
                        console.log("ended.");
                    }

                    AuthFactory.setJWTAuthInfo(authInfo);
                    //console.log("authinfoo1234: "  + authInfo);
          //          localStorage.setItem("authinfo",authInfo);
                    console.log("authorities: " + authInfo.authorities);


                    $state.go("dashboard.home");
                }

                function errorCB(response) {
                    let error = response.data;
                    if (error && error.status === 401) {
                        ctrl.authMessage = error.message;
                    }
                    else {
                        console.error(response);
                        ctrl.authMessage = 'No response from server';
                    }
                }

            }

        }


    ]);
```

I have a very strange problem: I'm using Intellj, and it tells me in lines

```
console.log("roles: " + JSON.stringify(authInfo.authorities));

console.log("userType: " + authInfo.userRole);
```

but if I comment lines with localStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem, console prints on output correct userType and userRole; if I add those lines, console prints out this message:

> TypeError
>   ​
>   columnNumber: 17
>   ​
>   fileName: "http://localhost:63342/ISSSR_frontend/app/scripts/service/AuthFactory.js"
>   ​
>   lineNumber: 59
>   ​
>   message: "authInfo.authorities is undefined"

I really don't understand, why it says me that it cannot resolve variable, but it can print out it?

Comment: Can you share AuthFactory source too?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I could not deploy your code would you please prepare codepen or flickr.

Some points that I can mention is below:
instead of use console.log("username: " + authInfo.username); use : `console.log('username : ',authInfo.username)`
Instead of JSON.stringify(authInfo.authorities) use : `angular.toJson(authInfo.authorities,true)`
Also console.log(response) to see what it returns.